# dynamic or object in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, object, dynamic

I'm using a javascript dll in c# that evaluate a javascript scope.

For now, I always return the evaluated result by the javascript dll in a string.

However, I'm planning to change the way it's done. I created an `enum DataType`:

```
public enum DataType
{
    Integer,
    Decimal,
    Boolean,
    Text
}
```

So depending on the given datatype in a dropdownlist, I'm going to cast the result in an integer, decimal, boolean or text.

When I'm doing the cast, should I return a dynamic or an object of int, decimal, bool or string?

My understanding of the dynamic type is not that clear.

Comment: no, you should not return a dynamic object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to return a value whose type is determined at run time, and not at compile time, you should return `dynamic`. This will allow you to use the object in all appropriate types without C# giving you a compile time error, and possibly saving yourself from a few casting runtime errors caused by improper casts of object into a specific type.

```
public dynamic GetAnything(DataType dataType)
{
    switch(dataType)
    {
        case Integer:
            return 1;
        case Decimal:
            return 1.0;
        case Boolean:
            return true;
        case Text:
            return "1";
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do:

```
var result = GetAnything(DataType.Text) + 1;
```

Without having to perform an explicit cast.

This is no more dangerous than returning an object, as you would do:

```
var result = (int)GetAnythingAsObject(DataType.Text) + 1;
```

Which would cause a runtime cast exception since object is in fact a string. Where as with dynamic, this will work for all types that support the `+` operator.

You can read more about the difference between `object` and `dynamic` in this msdn article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/01/25/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-object-keywords.aspx

Note: dynamic requires .Net 4 and over

Comment: This is now the accepted answer, however, I don't think for the purposes of his problem it is of any use to dynamically determine the data type. I personally think this solution is worse than returning `object`.

Comment: @D.R. I see no indication of why dynamic would be worse than object. In both situations, the caller will need to be aware of the true runtime type of the value if it wants to use it. Using dynamic will clean the code from an abundance of casting and in some cases, will allow behaviour that would fail if using object.

Comment: @D.R. I highly recommend you read the msdn article I linked to, it will clear out your fears of using dynamic. Here I quote the conclusion: "there is no need to fear that someone can break your code by using dynamic features. It is no more (and again, no less) dangerous than the object keyword." [...] "if you often use the object keyword and have to perform a lot of casting and/or use reflection to call methods and properties of objects, you probably should take a look at the dynamic keyword" [...] "In some cases it’s more convenient than object and with less code to write."

Comment: I guess the problem comes with performance, the only thing he does with the result is to check the type and output it to the user accordingly.

Comment: @D.R. I can't comment on the performance. I don't know if the way C# resolves the runtime type for dynamic is slower than casting object into another type. I would hope it's about the same, but a benchmark would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

No, dynamic types are for different usages. Use either an object or add generic calls for each enum type.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to return an object of a dynamic type.
You should use an object according to the selected data type.

The [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) type is a type that will be checked at runtime, not during the compilation time. Typically, it's used for scenarios like dynamic API, COM API, Office API (Interoperability libraries). I don't see a reason for using it in your scenario.